# How to set include path of file when running script from cmd

Tags: php, cmd, include-path

I m trying  to run php file from the command fine. here files are not included. Whrn I run php script from the browser its works perfect but when I run it from cmd then its giving error for that included file

PHP code

```
require("include/config.php");
include_once('include/classes/dbclass.php');
include_once('include/classes/send_emails.php');
```

Here suppose I put the code of dbclass.php file into main one and removed include_once('include/classes/dbclass.php'); line than there is no problem. So how to write include path or set include file when we used cmd to run php script

Comment: Please provide your directory structure..

Answer (score 12):

Your setup may have different php.ini option files for cmdline and web use,
you can either add the right include_path to the cmdline ini file (/etc/php5/cli/php.ini in my case), or pass it as a command line parameter:

```
php -d include_path=... script.php
```

Comment: How to add multiple include paths? Semicolon separated?

Answer (score 9):

I like doing:

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../include/file.php';
```

That way all includes and requires are relative to the local file.

Also, require, etc are not functions. You should not use parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change directory ("cd") in the cmd window to the directory of the file you are running before you run it. Then it should get the correct paths.

Comment: yep: cd /var/mydirectory && runmycron